# Firebase Cloud Function in Typescript integration with Flutter not Working

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am not able to pass document from firebase cloud function to flutter app.

So I am trying to perform a basic GET operation using a Firebase cloud function.
If I check the log then, cloud function is getting triggered.

```
export const onGetNewQuestion = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    var questions = db.collection('questions');

    //fetching random number from database
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log(random);

    //Select random question from database
    questions
      .where('id', '>=', random)
      .limit(1)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.data());
          //response.send(doc.data());
          response.json({ data: doc.data() });
          console.log(response);
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
  }
```

Now the response is captured in Flutter.

```
Future<Question> getQuestion() async {
    try {
      final result = await FirebaseFunctions.instance
          .httpsCallable('onGetNewQuestion')
          .call();

      print(result.toString());
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
      print(error.code);
      print(error.details);
      print(error.message);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
    }

    return Question(description: "", emoji: "", color: "");
  }
```

Here I am always triggering a Firebase Function Exception.

```
FirebaseFunctionExceptionFirebaseFunctionsException (\[firebase_functions/unavailable\]
```

where

```
error.code = deadline-exceeded
error.details = null
error.message = DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke an `onRequest` type function using the Firebase client SDK for callable type functions.  They are not compatible.  If you want to use the SDK to invoke a callable function, you will also need to [write a callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=1st).  As you can see from the linked documentation, they are a different types of functions defined with `onCall` instead of `onRequest`.

> It's important to keep in mind that HTTP callable functions are similar but not identical to HTTP functions. To use HTTP callable functions you must use the client SDK for your platform together with the backend API (or implement the protocol).

Comment: thank you, the issue is resolved. I made two changes in the cloud function.

1) Changed the function defination: 
 export const onGetNewQuestion = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {}

2) returned the data object instead of using response
return { data: "my data" };